# I need to find and configure AWS Lambda to accept a parameter. Is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud, aws-lambda

I need to find and configure AWS Lambda to accept a parameter and based on the input it has to process the request and insert data into service now portal.

Comment: What is your lambda trigger? API Gateway? What parameter are you asking? Query parameter (in the URL)?

Answer (score 2):

When invoking a lambda, you can add a payload, for example:

```
{
  "key3": "value3",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key1": "value1"
}
```

Which you can then call in your code:

```
def my_handler(event, context):
    print("First value is event['key1']")
    // do other stuff and return
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/get-started-create-function.html

So you could use this input to add a parameter for processing.

Answer (score 0):

You pass data `['abc', 'xyz']` in JSON format when invoke lambda function 
than in the lambda function get data like,

### Example:

```
event[0], event[1]
```

In `event[0]` value is `abc`